# Problemas al acceder a la información de los pixeles del render en SDL2

Tags: c

estoy teniendo problemas al intentar acceder a la información de los pixeles del Render en SDL2, he mirado un montón de foros, tutoriales y páginas y todas me dicen de hacerlo con un Surface, pero el caso es que el proyecto solo puede haber Render.

A parte de esto se que hay una función llama RenderReadPixels pero esta función solo me devuelve un 1 si ha leido correctamente todos los datos o 0 si ha habido algún problema al leerlos, pero no me devuelve ningún dato del pixel que ha leído por lo tanto no me está sirviendo de nada.

Muchas gracias por leerme!!

Comment: Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Realizar un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! agregale un valor aleatorio a cada fila y luego ordena por el mismo

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderReadPixels

Los píxeles se obtienen a través del parámetro `void* pixels` de la función, que es un array con valores sobre el color y depende del formato(parámetro `Uint32 format`) de la imagen y las dimensiones en píxeles de esta. Por ejemplo:

Si el formato de la imagen es `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGB888`, significa que la imagen utiliza 3 canales(**R**ed, **G**reen y **B**lue); y que cada canal utiliza **8**bits(1 byte). Así que la cantidad de elementos que devuelve `void* pixels` es de:

```
width * height * 3 // ancho x alto de la imagen(o render) x 3 canales(RGB).
```

Una vez obtenidos los píxeles en un puntero de tipo void, y asumiendo que la imagen tiene el formato antes mencionado, si quieremos obtener el color del primer píxel:

```
Uint8 r = pixels[0];
Uint8 g = pixels[1];
Uint8 b = pixels[2];
```

En cuanto al parámetro `int pitch` de la función, tengo entendido que es el ancho de la imagen multiplicado por la cantidad de bytes por color:

```
ancho * 3; // ancho de la imagen x 3 canales RGB para cada color.
```